# MAMP - #2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, mamp

Im trying to import a database thats 8MB (i cant make it smaller) with MAMP and I keep getting  the error below.

Ive read that I need to change my max_allowed_packet but I think ive done this and it still doesn't work. Is there a way I can find out what the max_allowed_packet (and any other relevant settings) are set to?

Or does anyone have any other solutions to try? Thanks

Error
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `cache_menu` (`cid`, `data`, `expire`, `created`, `serialized`) VALUES ('links:management:tree-data:en:ec99d3452fef1ede622e66c68ba908b1dad455aa71f5e68648aeec6488b89c88', 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[...]

MySQL said:

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying my-large.cnf to MAMP/Library and renaming it to my.cnf (and restarting MAMP) fixed this.

Comment: Is that your own file?!