# SQL syntax errors when importing database into phpMyAdmin (MAMP)

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, mamp

In order to import a 120Mb database into phpMyAdmin with MAMP I split it up using the following:

`split -l 100 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/database_test_wordpress.sql /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/dbpart-`

However when importing the second part I get the error:

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE  `wp_comments` (

 `comment_ID` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `comment_post_ID` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `comment_author` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
 `comment_author_email` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `comment_author_url` VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `comment_author_IP` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `comment_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `comment_date_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `comment_content` TEXT NOT NULL ,
 `comment_karma` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `comment_approved` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1',
 `comment_agent` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `comment_type` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `comment_parent` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `user_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
PRIMARY KEY (  `comment_ID` ) ,
KEY  `comment_post_ID` (  `comment_post_ID` ) ,
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 18
```

Do I need to upgrade the database somehow? Or am I way off?! Sorry, new to this :-)

Note: I first tried increasing `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size` in MAMP's php.ini but on import I got a `MySQL server has gone away` error.

Comment: You can not split a file containing SQL commands spanning multiple lines just “randomly” by x lines and still expect it to work …

Comment: Try using php to import the sql file by reading the file `file_get_contents`, then `mysql_query`. This way you won't have to split up the sql file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for pointing out that `split` was not the way to go!

Instead I managed to upload the original 120Mb file by editing the following limits before restarting MAMP:

In MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini I changed the `memory_limit` to `200M`, the `post_max_size` to `200M` and the `upload_max_filesize` to `120M`.

I then copied MAMP/Library/support-files/my-large.cnf to MAMP/Library and renamed it to my.cnf before setting `max_allowed_packet` to `100M`

Was pointed in this direction MAMP FAQs and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13613140/767761

Answer (score 1):

`split` is a linux command that will just slice text. You can't just do that and expect an import to work. In your particular example, the creation of a table is not being properly finished by a `;`, which means you are most likely missing the creation of indexes or constraints below the cut part of the text.

I wouldn't slice the file at all and import the whole SQL file from the console instead of using php for that. This should do the trick:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: Thanks Mosty, as I said I'm a newbie! - So I tried this `mysql -u root -p druglessdoctor < /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/druglessdoctor/database_drugless_wordpress2.sql` and got this `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p druglessdoctor < /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/druglessdoctor/datab' at line 1`.

Comment: You seem to be running that in the `mysql` prompt. You should do that in your linux prompt (just quit mysql and you'll be there :)

Comment: Yup I'm lost. On a Mac, I do this in Terminal?

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me! But I just get `-bash: mysql: command not found` so I googled it and found I need to put something like this first `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot` which allows me to use say `show databases;` and see all of them - However not sure how to then use the line you suggested to target `druglessdoctor`?

Comment: You must not get into the `mysql` prompt. Do this from the terminal itself. Assuming `druglessdoctor` is your database, just write that `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p druglessdoctor < /path/to/the/file.sql`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42429/discussion-between-caroline-elisa-and-mosty-mostacho)

Comment: Thanks Mosty but I couldn't get rid of those pesky `MySQL server has gone away` errors. So instead I went back to dealing with the size limits and managed to upload the original file.